# $\left< u, v\right> \stackrel{?}{=} \left< v, u \right>$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For some vector space $V$, is it true that

$$
\left< u, v \right> = \left< v, u \right>
$$

for all $u, v \in V$? Does this only hold if $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ or if $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ as well?

Comment: I've seen this property listed in my lower-division linear algebra textbook but not in my upper-division textbook. The difference between the two is that in the upper-division course, we consider complex vector space as well as real vector spaces.

Comment: It depends on how you define $\langle u,v\rangle$. If this means inner product, then yes.

Comment: If $V$ is a real inner product space, then this is certainly true. On the other hand, if $V$ is a complex inner product space, then the analogous property, instead, is $\langle u,v \rangle = \overline{\langle v,u \rangle}$; otherwise, positive-definiteness would fail.